# What badges did these IDs used to represent?

Tags: discussion, badges

The [Enthusiast badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast)'s ID is 71. Changing the ID, I found that 70 and 72 are both deleted, which seems odd.

Does anyone know what those two badges used to be?

Comment: I imagine a tag badge for a now deleted tag, not sure how it would be possible to check

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but maybe a mod could? Or staff? :)

Comment: As I said, it's just for fun, and I don't see what's wrong with it. **Someone** _has_ to have the time. :D

Comment: /shrug maybe they can look for tags that were deleted end of May/beginning of June 2009.

Comment: Really, why not? I would've added the `fun` tag were there any :)

Comment: Odd? 70 and 72? Hardly odd.

Comment: Didn't they get rid of the badge related to deleting a poorly scored question/answer because it was seen as sarcastic? https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/

Comment: @BSMP No, they retired them (read: still there but no longer attainable), tumbleweed is still there as 63 for example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Badge Ids are notoriously unstable across the Stack Exchange network. There is no rhyme or rhythm in how they are created.

[This table](https://github.com/gurkensaas/StackExchange-Badge-IDs/blob/main/tables/table.csv) shows the real life effect of that (do visit [All Badge IDs on every network](https://stackapps.com/questions/9147) for more formats and extra context).

It could well be there never had been a 70 or 72 because by the time a dev needed to add the next badge after 71 their head was already in the nineties.

In [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254605/can-we-have-a-working-route-if-we-use-the-id-from-the-badges-table) not having stable badgeid-s' is a pain as well.

As indicated by [Larnu in their excellent comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413190/what-badges-did-this-ids-used-to-represent/413191?noredirect=1#comment880406_413191) supported by prior answers of me on MSE [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291851/are-reviews-in-the-review-queues-numbered-consecutively/291853#291853), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298852) the simple fact that SQL Server is used as a database with its typical IDENTITY column behavior could explain the gaps as well.

Comment: If I were to guess, the ID is generated by an `IDENTITY` (as Stack Overflow use SQL Server), which is documented to *not* provide incremental values, and such behaviour is by design. The number could be skipped for many reasons; an `INSERT` might have failed and the valued used, an unexpected restart caused the cache to be lost (on some instances this causes a skip of 1,000). It might be the value did exist, and was `DELETE`d. At the end of the day, an `IDENTITY` is just an arbitrary number; what number is it is utterly meaningless.

Comment: Ah, now that's interesting. I never though of that.